# Unit testing component with angulartics2 - Can't bind to 'angularticsCategory' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular-cli

I am starting a project using Angular 2.0.0 stable release created with angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.14 and angulartics 1.1.9.

I am trying to start some simple unit testing and am recording clicks on a button component

```
<div class="sidebar-toggle" (click)="toggleSideBar()" angulartics2On="click" angularticsCategory="{{ expanded ? 'expand': 'collapse' }}">
   //divContent
</div>
```

However, when I run the test which is simple bootstrapping the component I get the error

> Can't bind to 'angularticsCategory' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

The app works fine but the issue only comes up in testing. I can't find an example where someone is having the same error in testing. I know I am missing something like not properly exposing the angulartics2 lib in my karma.conf OR not injecting the Angulartics or a mocked dependency in my Testbed config.

Really lost and would like to know if anyone is having similar problems. Can provide more code snippets if needed but don't want to dump the whole file nobody's got time to read that!

Comment: I've never used this library, but looking at [the tests](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/blob/v1.1.9/src/test.mocks.ts#L73), there's a `Angulartics2Module`. Did you import that into your TestBed configuration?

Comment: Thanks, adding that module to `imports` property in the TestBed config worked. Thanks!

Comment: Are you really using Angular 2.0.0? Why? I am just curious :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case to get Angulatics2 unit tests to work I had to:

**1) Import Angulartics2Module into the root app.module.ts**

```
import { Angulartics2Module } from 'angulartics2';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    Angulartics2Module.forRoot({ developerMode: !environment.production }),
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**2) Enable tracking in app.component.ts**

```
import { Angulartics2GoogleGlobalSiteTag } from 'angulartics2/gst';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    public angulartics2GoogleGlobalSiteTag: Angulartics2GoogleGlobalSiteTag,
  ) {
    this.angulartics2GoogleGlobalSiteTag.startTracking();
  }
}
```

**3) Import Angulartics2Module.forRoot() and Angulartics2 provider in to app.component.spec.ts**

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Angulartics2, Angulartics2Module } from 'angulartics2';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        Angulartics2Module.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
      ],
      providers: [
        Angulartics2,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

and for any other component.spec.ts files that you have using the Angulatics2 directives.

Comment: When I do the above suggested I get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
 error properties: Object({ ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 33800193, rootNodeFlags: 33554433, ....
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined


Would appreciate if you can provide some help here.

Comment: I wrote this two years ago, it's possible that the module has changed since. You would need to check the guide